# Unable to access developer command prompt for compile c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Im first time posting a thread here .. i really tired of searching for a solution for my problem that i don't able to access developer cmd for compile C# 
i have a windows phone sdk 7.1 already installed in my system and following version of .NET frame work
v2.0.50
v3.0
v3.5
v4
v4.0
respectively ..
And i tried to configure the visual studio cmd from visual studio 'tool' Menu 
but its(i think its system cmd only) not working and can't run 'csc' command , giving an error

''Warning CS2008: No source files specified''error cs1562:output without the source must have the/out put specified''

I don't want an IDE but i would like to do the programming in Notepad and compile it with system CMD .. i read somewhere in microsoft website visual studio express not come with developer command line utility (correct me if im wrong )
.. Please help me to solve this issue, i like to use notepad instead of visual studio to program C#

thanks

Comment: In a day like this, using notepad is always a sad approach on Windows. The csc error is desired because you indeed does not serve the parameters it expected. Try to read documentation about csc and MSBuild and you might learn what you missed.

Comment: You don't have these shortcuts under `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 | Visual Studio Tools`?  Shortcuts for the various dev command prompts are located there.